# AngularJS need to store userdata , should be available to entire application

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, session-storage, angular-local-storage

I need to store userdata, should be available to entire application, should be accessible to required controllers, after searching I found a few options to store.

- using a service to controllers
- $sessionStorage
- $localStorage

of all the above could u please tell me which is the best practice? Or is there any other solution other than the above 3.

Comment: what is the purpose of your application? is it going to hold any sensitive data?

Comment: @Aravind , store the userData so that we can permit the resources based on the authorities it holds, and this userData should be accessible to all the controllers, when required in the view it should be usable

Comment: in which framework you are using backend?

Comment: @Aravind Spring Rest, oracle and LDAP

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple google search might have told you a lot about the best thing? there is no single best thing it's all depends upon your use case.

Services are the best way to interchange data between controllers.
if you don't want to persist the data(if data don't want to be there if the page is reloaded) you can use a service, If you want to persist the data you can use localstorage.